# Restore certificates to fix curl error 60

Tags: windows, curl, certificate-store

A while ago, I had to install some ssl certificates on my Windows laptop (used only for work). Ever since, I noticed some odd issues when using curl.

```
curl https://www.google.com                                                                                                               (main)dotfiles
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

I figured since this showed up when I installed the certificate, maybe just uninstalling out might fix it. But I think I ended up uninstalling something else, is there a way to restore my certificates to their default/original state?

### How else does this affect you?

Suppose I would like to install some CLI in WSL, this particular app can be installed through cargo.

```
cargo install --locked zellij                                                                                                            
    Updating crates.io index
error: failed to download from `https://crates.io/api/v1/crates/zellij/0.34.4/download`

Caused by:
  [60] SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK (server certificate verification failed. CAfile: none CRLfile: none)
```

Some time ago, I was unable to install some database drivers for [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/)